# SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11, babel-polyfill

I have hit a wall with this issue. Help in any way is greatly appreciated.

I have a react-app (created using create-react-app CLI) which works perfectly on all browsers except IE. I have two tabs; one login and another signup. The login page loads fine, but on clicking the signup tab I get the above-mentioned error on my console

These are my dependencies

````
        "@types/react": "^16.9.41",
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
        "auth0-js": "^9.13.2",
        "hookrouter": "^1.2.3",
        "html-to-react": "^1.4.3",
        "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
        "password-checklist": "^6.0.0",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.10.4",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.10.4",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.10.4",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign": "^7.10.4",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript": "^7.10.4",
        "@babel/polyfill": "^7.10.4",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.10.4",
        "@types/auth0-js": "^9.12.4",
        "@types/auth0-lock": "^11.4.13",
        "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.5",
        "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.6",
        "@types/jest": "^24.9.1",
        "@types/jwt-decode": "^2.2.1",
        "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
        "@types/sinon": "^9.0.4",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.3.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.3.0",
        "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.5.1",
        "babel-jest": "^26.0.1",
        "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
        "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "6.18.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "6.26.2",
        "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "0.4.13",
        "babel-polyfill": "6.26.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "1.6.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
        "chalk": "^2.4.1",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
        "core-js": "^3.6.5",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
        "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
        "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
        "enzyme-to-json": "^3.4.4",
        "es6-object-assign": "^1.1.0",
        "es6-shim": "^0.35.5",
        "eslint": "^7.2.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
        "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.12.2",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.21.2",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.0.4",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
        "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
        "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.1",
        "html-loader": "^1.1.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
        "image-webpack-loader": "^6.0.0",
        "jest": "^24.9.0",
        "jest-cli": "^24.8.0",
        "jest-transform-css": "^2.0.0",
        "jsdom": "^16.2.2",
        "jsdom-global": "^3.0.2",
        "lint-staged": "7.0.5",
        "lodash-ts-imports-loader": "^1.1.2",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
        "prettier": "^1.13.5",
        "promise-polyfill": "^8.1.3",
        "react-hot-loader": "^3.1.1",
        "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
        "sinon": "^9.0.2",
        "source-map-loader": "^0.2.3",
        "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.6",
        "ts-jest": "^26.0.0",
        "ts-loader": "^7.0.4",
        "tslint": "5.10.0",
        "tslint-config-prettier": "1.12.0",
        "tslint-react": "3.6.0",
        "tslint-react-hooks": "^2.2.2",
        "typescript": "^3.9.3",
        "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
        "url-loader": "^4.1.0",
        "url-search-params-polyfill": "^8.1.0",
        "webpack": "4.42.0",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "3.8.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }```
=======

and this is my polyfill

    ```entry: {
            client: ["@babel/polyfill", client]
        },```

=======Error i see on the console

[![Not so useful ][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9mXw.png
````

Comment: I suggest you try to add `import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';` in the `src/index.js` file. Add `ie 11` in `browserlist` for both **production** and **development** section in `package.json` file. If you are using `react-scripts` version 3.3.0 or higher then try to downgrade it to version 3.2.0. See whether it helps to fix the issue or not.